# Text Beside an Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make photo with some text besides it, im tryng to use `vertical-align=text-top` but the next line of the text goes to below the image:

https://jsfiddle.net/afuqewaq/2/

How put all the text beside the image like this [image]?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add `float: left;` in image styles

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the image in a div and set it and the text (suitably wrapped if necessary) to `display:inline-block`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg" style="vertical-align:text-top; width:200px">
  </div>
  <p>

    ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br>ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br>BLABLABLA
    <br>

  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this easily is by using flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 1 10%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.text {
 flex: 1 1 80%;
 margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
  </div>
  <div classs="text">
    <p>Your text there</p>
    <p> To fill the conatiner</p>
    <p>Or not to fill, your choice</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This creates a flex container. Then provides two blocks for an image and text. Giving each of them ample space within the container. You may need to toy around with the text layout to get things aligned as-needed within that block. But, the primary issue of the layout is solved.

Comment: Please note that flexbox [isn't supported in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: And IE9 has no support from MS anymore. Aside from one OS version which as minuscule usage. As  with any technology, check your analytics for browsers you should support.

Comment: I will not go into that debate, but as for now [IE9 still represent around 6.5% of the browser market](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0). Ignore it or not, that's a commercial question and depends of your company policy, but it worth to warn readers about it. I'm only talking about technical aspect here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the text from going under the image you can use two `<div>`elements which both `float:left`, **provided it has enough space to be displayed next to the image, if it doesn't fit next to it it will be displayed under the image.**

```
<div class="">
  <div style="float:left">
    <img src="http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg" style="vertical-align:text-top; width:200px;float:left;">
  </div>
<div style="float:left;">
  <p>
    ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN
    <br /> ALBERT EINSTEIN2
    <br /> BLABLABLA
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Try using a table in the following way.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="yourImage" height="150" width="150" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div>
                <!-- Rest of your text -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please  don't use a table for  layout. Flexbox is so much more well suited for these tasks.

Comment: This is not recommended as using <tables> for layout is no longer the best way forward. <table> is for tabular data only.

Answer (score -4):

In CSS there is a property called padding, enclose your property in `div` tag and then you can use something like the following:

```
div{padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px }.
```

These values are respectively from top right bottom left. Try these values and you are good to go.